# Set different values while iterating in Java

Tags: java

I'm working on an application where I have to store different MultipartFile files (jpgs, pngs, etc) and im trying to improve this duplicated code:

```java
store(dogfile, dogDirectory, vetDTO::setDog);
store(catFile, catDirectory, vetDTO::setCat);
store(lionFile, lionDirectory, vetDTO::setLion);
store(bugFile, bugDirectory, vetDTO::setBug); 
store(mouseFile, mouseDirectory, vetDTO::setMouse); 
store(bunnyFile, bunnyDirectory, vetDTO::setBunny);
```

I tried storing each file and directory in a Map like this:

```java
Map<MultipartFile, String> filesToStore = new HashMap<MultipartFile, String>();
filesToStore.put(dogfile, dogDirectory);
filesToStore.put(catFile, catDirectory);
filesToStore.put(lionFile, lionDirectory);
filesToStore.put(bugFile, bugDirectory);
filesToStore.put(bunnyFile, bunnyDirectory);
filesToStore.forEach((f,d) -> store(f, d, vetDTO::set...));
```

But the last line gives me an error because I cannot manage to use each setter while iterating, and I'm really confused about how to achieve this.

Is it possible to use different setters while iterating?

Comment: Could you provide a full compilable code?

Comment: You could store the setter reference as well in the map but you would need a custom type tuple type for the value. And even then I don't think the code would be more readable..

Comment: May be write a function where you could check what type of setter(custom setter) is required and set it.

Comment: I suggest you add more context to the question to get better understanding. In current point of view, I wonder why you are put everything inside a map `(Map<MultipartFile, String>)` and then iterate over it to call the `store` method. Why don't you directly call `store` method?

Answer (score 1):

It's not clear what is your compilable code, but I can give you a hint.

You can remove the duplication with a simple loop:

```java
Main context = new Main();
VetDTO vetDTO = new VetDTO();

for (Animal animal : Animal.values())
    animal.store(context, vetDTO);
```

To do so, you have to encapsulate the code related to the specific animal in a separate class.

```java
public class Main {

    private MultipartFile dogFile;
    private MultipartFile catFile;
    private MultipartFile lionFile;
    private MultipartFile bugFile;
    private MultipartFile mouseFile;
    private MultipartFile bunnyFile;

    private String dogDirectory;
    private String catDirectory;
    private String lionDirectory;
    private String bugDirectory;
    private String mouseDirectory;
    private String bunnyDirectory;

    enum Animal {
        DOG(context -> context.dogFile, context -> context.dogDirectory, (directory, vetDTO) -> vetDTO.setDog(directory)),
        CAT(context -> context.catFile, context -> context.catDirectory, (directory, vetDTO) -> vetDTO.setCat(directory)),
        LION(context -> context.lionFile, context -> context.lionDirectory, (directory, vetDTO) -> vetDTO.setLion(directory)),
        BUG(context -> context.bugFile, context -> context.bugDirectory, (directory, vetDTO) -> vetDTO.setBug(directory)),
        MOUSE(context -> context.mouseFile, context -> context.mouseDirectory, (directory, vetDTO) -> vetDTO.setMouse(directory)),
        BUNNY(context -> context.bunnyFile, context -> context.bunnyDirectory, (directory, vetDTO) -> vetDTO.setBunny(directory));

        private final Function<Main, MultipartFile> getMultipartFile;
        private final Function<Main, String> getDirectory;
        private final BiConsumer<String, VetDTO> setAnimal;

        Animal(Function<Main, MultipartFile> getMultipartFile,
                Function<Main, String> getDirectory,
                BiConsumer<String, VetDTO> setAnimal) {
            this.getMultipartFile = getMultipartFile;
            this.getDirectory = getDirectory;
            this.setAnimal = setAnimal;
        }

        public void store(Main context, VetDTO vetDTO) {
            MultipartFile multipartFile = getMultipartFile.apply(context);
            String directory = getDirectory.apply(context);
            setAnimal.accept(directory, vetDTO);
        }
    }

    public static class VetDTO {

        public void setDog(String dogDirectory) {}

        public void setCat(String catDirectory) {}

        public void setLion(String lionDirectory) {}

        public void setBug(String bugDirectory) {}

        public void setMouse(String mouseDirectory) {}

        public void setBunny(String bunnyDirectory) {}

    }

}
```